# Ошибка при кодировании изображения в base64

Tags: java, android, base64

Пытаюсь кодировать картинку на андроид в base64 таким способом:

```
try {
      File sFile = new File(padssf);     
      byte[] data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(sFile);
      String encoded = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(data);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

подключаю библиотеку:

```
compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.2.12'
```

добавляю импорт:

```
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
```

Но вылетает ошибка конкретно на строчке

```
String encoded = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(data);
```

никак не могу найти причину, просьба поделиться опытом, с чем это может быть связано?

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
     at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.initConverter(DatatypeConverter.java:155)
     at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(DatatypeConverter.java:626)
     at bpv_jinetta.com.updater.home.AddNewsActivity.jetzt(AddNewsActivity.java:153)
     at bpv_jinetta.com.updater.home.AddNewsActivity.onActivityResult(AddNewsActivity.java:120)
     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5472)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3406)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3453)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:150)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1328)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: java.lang.Error: javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl not found
     at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.<clinit>(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:907)
     at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.initConverter(DatatypeConverter.java:155) 
     at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(DatatypeConverter.java:626) 
     at bpv_jinetta.com.updater.home.AddNewsActivity.jetzt(AddNewsActivity.java:153) 
     at bpv_jinetta.com.updater.home.AddNewsActivity.onActivityResult(AddNewsActivity.java:120) 
     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5472) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3406) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3453) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:150) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1328) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl not found
     at javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance(DatatypeFactory.java:103)
     at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.<clinit>(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:905)
     at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.initConverter(DatatypeConverter.java:155) 
     at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(DatatypeConverter.java:626) 
     at bpv_jinetta.com.updater.home.AddNewsActivity.jetzt(AddNewsActivity.java:153) 
     at bpv_jinetta.com.updater.home.AddNewsActivity.onActivityResult(AddNewsActivity.java:120) 
     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5472) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3406) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3453) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:150) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1328) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl" on path: /data/app/bpv_jinetta.com.updater-2.apk
     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
     at javax.xml.datatype.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:138)
     at javax.xml.datatype.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:219)
     at javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance(DatatypeFactory.java:96)
     at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.<clinit>(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:905) 
     at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.initConverter(DatatypeConverter.java:155) 
     at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(DatatypeConverter.java:626) 
     at bpv_jinetta.com.updater.home.AddNewsActivity.jetzt(AddNewsActivity.java:153) 
     at bpv_jinetta.com.updater.home.AddNewsActivity.onActivityResult(AddNewsActivity.java:120) 
     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5472) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3406) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3453) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:150) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1328) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Я ничего про это не знаю, но [как будто бы](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4830846/5812238) конвертировать в base64 можно и без внешних библиотек, с помощью метода [`Base64::encodeToString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#encodeToString(byte%5B%5D%2C%20int))

Comment: Да, спасибо я так и поступил, можете написать ответ, я отмечу как правильный.

Comment: Не за что) Напишите лучше вы ответ, а я ему плюсик поставлю)